Failed to load module script due to incorrect MIME type when deploying React app using Azure DevOps and hosting on Azure App Service
Working on a project that is using React, Azure Devops and Azure appServices. The code is running is running on local machine. But I am getting this error when I deploy the app and open using the website link provided.
File structure can be seen in the image.
Error.
File structure. 
Not sure how to tackle this problem. Any help would be appreciated.
Logs:
2024-08-06T19:24:40.3684741Z Container start method called.
2024-08-06T19:24:40.3894150Z Establishing network.
2024-08-06T19:24:40.3900492Z Pulling image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod.
2024-08-06T19:24:40.6139980Z Container start method called.
2024-08-06T19:24:40.6253770Z Establishing network.
2024-08-06T19:24:40.6256018Z Pulling image: appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod.
2024-08-06T19:24:44.7921572Z Container is starting.
2024-08-06T19:24:44.7992402Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-08-06T19:24:44.7994742Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-08-06T19:24:44.7996487Z Mounting volumes.
2024-08-06T19:24:44.8184866Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:44.8681569Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-08-06T19:24:44.8780341Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:44.8895092Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:44.9084764Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:44.9664357Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:47.0951633Z Creating container.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1127942Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1135413Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stdout_bf0e8721393e4747a0b75cc6792a354d.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1325585Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stdout_bf0e8721393e4747a0b75cc6792a354d.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1331268Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stdout_bf0e8721393e4747a0b75cc6792a354d for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1337012Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stdout_bf0e8721393e4747a0b75cc6792a354d.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1346065Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stdout_bf0e8721393e4747a0b75cc6792a354d.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1517665Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stderr_711103d851e8406882c49c04b95b6d94.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1520602Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stderr_711103d851e8406882c49c04b95b6d94.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1522276Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stderr_711103d851e8406882c49c04b95b6d94 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1523924Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stderr_711103d851e8406882c49c04b95b6d94.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1526541Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c/stderr_711103d851e8406882c49c04b95b6d94.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.1540162Z Creating container with image: appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod
2024-08-06T19:24:47.2416042Z Container is starting.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.2511872Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.2515395Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.2517019Z Mounting volumes.
2024-08-06T19:24:47.2520546Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:47.2780572Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-08-06T19:24:47.2980723Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:47.3665780Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:47.3764143Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:24:47.3954904Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7100736Z Creating container.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7107840Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7111165Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stdout_832dbcee613347e7826b28505b776b2f.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7294601Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stdout_832dbcee613347e7826b28505b776b2f.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7300602Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stdout_832dbcee613347e7826b28505b776b2f for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7307173Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stdout_832dbcee613347e7826b28505b776b2f.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7313647Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stdout_832dbcee613347e7826b28505b776b2f.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7468146Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stderr_f1781c72530b4168ada0016c1a84cd19.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7472231Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stderr_f1781c72530b4168ada0016c1a84cd19.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7473955Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stderr_f1781c72530b4168ada0016c1a84cd19 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7475729Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stderr_f1781c72530b4168ada0016c1a84cd19.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7477054Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2/stderr_f1781c72530b4168ada0016c1a84cd19.
2024-08-06T19:25:23.7478297Z Creating container with image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-06T19:25:55.1097578Z Starting container: zeusemployeeportal_kudu_80e4783c.
2024-08-06T19:25:55.1303211Z Starting container: zeusemployeeportal_31c3dea2.
2024-08-06T19:25:55.4238807Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-06T19:25:55.4437978Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-06T19:25:55.4706236Z Container is running.
2024-08-06T19:25:55.6553924Z Container start method finished after 75041 ms.
2024-08-06T19:25:59.3699748Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-06T19:25:59.3722865Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-06T19:25:59.3730265Z Container is running.
2024-08-06T19:26:00.4733340Z Container start method finished after 80104 ms.
2024-08-06T19:26:22.3151580Z Container is terminating. Grace period: 0 seconds.
2024-08-06T19:26:22.5979280Z Stop and delete container. Retry count = 0
2024-08-06T19:26:22.6066444Z Stopping container: zeusemployeeportal_kudu_dd785acc.
2024-08-06T19:26:24.1610735Z Deleting container: zeusemployeeportal_kudu_dd785acc. Retry count = 0
2024-08-06T19:26:25.2621054Z Container spec TerminationMessagePolicy  path 
2024-08-06T19:26:25.2812620Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 2951 ms.
2024-08-06T19:26:54.0858698Z Container is terminating. Grace period: 5 seconds.
2024-08-06T19:26:54.1451626Z Stop and delete container. Retry count = 0
2024-08-06T19:26:54.1531673Z Stopping container: zeusemployeeportal_e1d3db8f.
2024-08-06T19:26:54.9058703Z Deleting container: zeusemployeeportal_e1d3db8f. Retry count = 0
2024-08-06T19:26:55.6529556Z Container spec TerminationMessagePolicy  path 
2024-08-06T19:26:55.6539599Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 1566 ms.


2024-08-08T00:32:58.9119295Z Container start method called.
2024-08-08T00:32:58.9343396Z Establishing network.
2024-08-08T00:32:58.9404902Z Pulling image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod.
2024-08-08T00:32:58.0859044Z Container start method called.
2024-08-08T00:32:58.5446821Z Establishing network.
2024-08-08T00:32:58.5519669Z Pulling image: appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.1911140Z Container is starting.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.1923553Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.2100831Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.2102400Z Mounting volumes.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.3407291Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:23.6020708Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-08-08T00:33:23.7091911Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:23.7963498Z Container is starting.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.7964764Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.7965353Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.7965769Z Mounting volumes.
2024-08-08T00:33:23.7967335Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:23.8843705Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-08-08T00:33:24.2469013Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:24.3041732Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:24.3648468Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:24.3641569Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:24.5086938Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:24.6663167Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:25.9266459Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:33:27.4236390Z Creating container.
2024-08-08T00:33:27.5990289Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-08-08T00:33:27.6070100Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stdout_241cbdda433741b38eab782280d7c604.
2024-08-08T00:33:27.7169152Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stdout_241cbdda433741b38eab782280d7c604.
2024-08-08T00:33:27.7468207Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stdout_241cbdda433741b38eab782280d7c604 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T00:33:27.8055686Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stdout_241cbdda433741b38eab782280d7c604.
2024-08-08T00:33:27.8322331Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stdout_241cbdda433741b38eab782280d7c604.
2024-08-08T00:33:27.8330641Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stderr_4ebb8b82bb3844c3a59e3a7145be8e7d.
2024-08-08T00:33:28.0110721Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stderr_4ebb8b82bb3844c3a59e3a7145be8e7d.
2024-08-08T00:33:28.0295513Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stderr_4ebb8b82bb3844c3a59e3a7145be8e7d for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T00:33:28.0469175Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stderr_4ebb8b82bb3844c3a59e3a7145be8e7d.
2024-08-08T00:33:28.1655188Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce/stderr_4ebb8b82bb3844c3a59e3a7145be8e7d.
2024-08-08T00:33:28.1822462Z Creating container with image: appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod
2024-08-08T00:33:32.4544544Z Creating container.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.4574478Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.4850891Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stdout_2235bbfebea34c5c8bda4ca0ac16e0cc.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.5155914Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stdout_2235bbfebea34c5c8bda4ca0ac16e0cc.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.5454635Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stdout_2235bbfebea34c5c8bda4ca0ac16e0cc for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.5522469Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stdout_2235bbfebea34c5c8bda4ca0ac16e0cc.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.5535936Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stdout_2235bbfebea34c5c8bda4ca0ac16e0cc.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.5548157Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stderr_5a76bdde54b04cb3b116b69ed0d357c5.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.5624459Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stderr_5a76bdde54b04cb3b116b69ed0d357c5.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.5644086Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stderr_5a76bdde54b04cb3b116b69ed0d357c5 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.6320190Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stderr_5a76bdde54b04cb3b116b69ed0d357c5.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.6415151Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc/stderr_5a76bdde54b04cb3b116b69ed0d357c5.
2024-08-08T00:33:32.6614913Z Creating container with image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-08T00:35:34.2363829Z Starting container: zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc.
2024-08-08T00:35:37.0475529Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-08T00:35:37.2504991Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-08T00:35:37.8628677Z Container is running.
2024-08-08T00:35:40.7792688Z Container start method finished after 161847 ms.
2024-08-08T00:37:23.0715072Z Starting container: zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce.
2024-08-08T00:37:25.8752788Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-08T00:37:25.9028322Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-08T00:37:26.1296708Z Container is running.
2024-08-08T00:37:27.7440577Z Container start method finished after 269627 ms.
2024-08-08T00:53:29.2682659Z Container is terminating. Grace period: 0 seconds.
2024-08-08T00:53:27.8926429Z Container start method called.
2024-08-08T00:53:27.9503669Z Establishing network.
2024-08-08T00:53:27.9504843Z Pulling image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod.
2024-08-08T00:53:30.7348880Z Stop and delete container. Retry count = 0
2024-08-08T00:53:30.7448070Z Stopping container: zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce.
2024-08-08T00:53:31.3875804Z Deleting container: zeusemployeeportal_kudu_efda36ce. Retry count = 0
2024-08-08T00:53:32.5204180Z Container spec TerminationMessagePolicy  path 
2024-08-08T00:53:32.5232714Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 3251 ms.
2024-08-08T00:53:34.8507093Z Container is starting.
2024-08-08T00:53:34.8522570Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-08-08T00:53:34.8533541Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-08-08T00:53:34.8601335Z Mounting volumes.
2024-08-08T00:53:34.8634039Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:53:34.9125131Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-08-08T00:53:34.9284929Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:53:34.9406414Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:53:34.9480751Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:53:34.9798304Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2653660Z Creating container.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2669644Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2681267Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stdout_afdd40d6b1a3408cbde9915e631bfcf4.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2759251Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stdout_afdd40d6b1a3408cbde9915e631bfcf4.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2769921Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stdout_afdd40d6b1a3408cbde9915e631bfcf4 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2776280Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stdout_afdd40d6b1a3408cbde9915e631bfcf4.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2850662Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stdout_afdd40d6b1a3408cbde9915e631bfcf4.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2862709Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stderr_b0535fe9facb46bf95c6135d9bf65376.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.2874679Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stderr_b0535fe9facb46bf95c6135d9bf65376.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.3047926Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stderr_b0535fe9facb46bf95c6135d9bf65376 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.3065954Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stderr_b0535fe9facb46bf95c6135d9bf65376.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.3233405Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d/stderr_b0535fe9facb46bf95c6135d9bf65376.
2024-08-08T00:53:38.3246999Z Creating container with image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-08T00:53:39.7796789Z Starting container: zeusemployeeportal_6cb4891d.
2024-08-08T00:53:39.8781288Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-08T00:53:39.9089775Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-08T00:53:39.9162518Z Container is running.
2024-08-08T00:53:40.2211672Z Container start method finished after 12327 ms.
2024-08-08T00:54:51.7021978Z Container is terminating. Grace period: 5 seconds.
2024-08-08T00:54:51.7290415Z Stop and delete container. Retry count = 0
2024-08-08T00:54:51.7305420Z Stopping container: zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc.
2024-08-08T00:54:52.1200820Z Deleting container: zeusemployeeportal_9ce03cfc. Retry count = 0
2024-08-08T00:54:52.9747954Z Container spec TerminationMessagePolicy  path 
2024-08-08T00:54:52.9819941Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 1278 ms.
2024-08-08T18:27:34.2057574Z Container start method called.
2024-08-08T18:27:34.2120370Z Establishing network.
2024-08-08T18:27:34.2166640Z Pulling image: appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.0544706Z Container is starting.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.0556484Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.0567078Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.0604237Z Mounting volumes.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.0722721Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T18:27:37.1037554Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-08-08T18:27:37.1129368Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T18:27:37.1811892Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T18:27:37.2177317Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T18:27:37.2387625Z Nested mountpoint 
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3170705Z Creating container.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3180595Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3247418Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stdout_dda63a76ae404ea1aa369a43f967908a.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3285397Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stdout_dda63a76ae404ea1aa369a43f967908a.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3291475Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stdout_dda63a76ae404ea1aa369a43f967908a for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3346282Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stdout_dda63a76ae404ea1aa369a43f967908a.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3356783Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stdout_dda63a76ae404ea1aa369a43f967908a.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3370064Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stderr_baa9baebdd674250bf9e8beedb88a656.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3377799Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stderr_baa9baebdd674250bf9e8beedb88a656.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3462961Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stderr_baa9baebdd674250bf9e8beedb88a656 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3474787Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stderr_baa9baebdd674250bf9e8beedb88a656.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3558464Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f/stderr_baa9baebdd674250bf9e8beedb88a656.
2024-08-08T18:27:37.3633859Z Creating container with image: appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/kudulite:bookworm_20240522.2.tuxprod
2024-08-08T18:27:38.4548620Z Starting container: zeusemployeeportal_kudu_4cdf949f.
2024-08-08T18:27:38.6401325Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-08T18:27:38.6441364Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-08T18:27:38.6462796Z Container is running.
2024-08-08T18:27:38.7699112Z Container start method finished after 4516 ms.


Share Error in Text format.

Please provide more details about the issue

@Anirudh Narayanan If Possible, share your github repo?

Please share the yaml file used to deploy in Azure DevOps. Add a variable system.debug and set the value to true, then trigger the pipeline and share the error in the debug log.

i uploaded the code via vscode, I don't know where the YAML file is.
But i have uploaded the log does that help

@Anirudh Narayanan Please share your App.js and index.js code.

You said that you are deploying React app using Azure DevOps. How did you deploy app using Azure DevOps? Using YAML pipeline or classic release pipeline? If so, please share the yaml file or the screenshots of your classic release pipeline.
